# Is there a web log analyser that can understand processing time and parse querystring?

Tags: apache, logging, reporting, webserver, web-analytics

Does anyone know of an web log analyser that can both report on the 'processing time' field that Apache can store (%D), and also parse querystrings intelligently?

I've looked into some of the usual suspects eg AWStats and Webalyser but none I've looked at seem to offer either of these features.

Ideally, you'd be able to report on specific querystring parameters rather than simple 'page' requests, eg if my server showed hits to:

/someurl?blah=X&whatever=Y

/someurl?whatever=Y&blah=Z

I'd like it to be able to parse that intelligently, so if I ask for a report where 'whatever=Y' both URLs would be grouped together, whereas if I report on 'blah=X', they would be counted separately?

Any suggestions of off-the-shelf tools that can do this? FOSS or otherwise.

Yes I realise that I can write some awk or sed scripts to parse this sort of thing myself but I'm looking for someone to have done that hard work for me and present it in a nice chart or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

[logparser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07) from microsoft is a very versatile tool that can be used to parse server logs. It supports a SQL syntax so you can give powerful queries. THe only downside is that it is Windows only at this point.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. Looks promising.